# LinkedList to store LinkedList of Nodes

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have written a `LinkedList` class that accepts `Nodes` that stores `Integers`.

I have then created a `LinkedList stack = new LinkedList()`, and have added `Node`s to it if the data of the `Node`s are less than the data of the `Node`s that already exist in this `stack`.

If not, I want to put this old `stack` into a new `LinkedList` called `LinkedList pilesOfStacks`, and create a `newStack`  called `LinkedList newStack = new LinkedList()`, and add the larger `Node` into this `newStack`  which will also go into the `LinkedList pilesOfStacks`.

My question is; since I already created my `LinkedList` class to accept `Node`s, how do I make it a new `LinkedList` to accept `LinkedList`s of these `Nodes`, essentially creating different piles of `LinkedList`s in a `LinkedList`?

This is what I have so far:

```
public void sort(LinkedList listOfInts)
{

  LinkedList<LinkedList> piles = new LinkedList<LinkedList>();

  LinkedList stack = new LinkedList();

  for(int i = 0; i < listOfInts.getSize(); i++)
  {
    Node x = listOfInts.pop();
    for(int j = 0; j < piles.getSize(); j++)
    {
      Node y = piles.peek(); //check first element of each pile

      if( ( ((Comparable)y.getData()).compareTo(x.getData()) ) <= 0)
      {
        stack.push(x);
        break;
      }
    }
    stack.push(x); //put value in stack
    piles.add(stack);
  }
}
```

Edit: If I could use an array, I would create a double array to something of the effect `Node[][] array = new Node[20][20];` and then search it with `Node[i][0]`, but since I can only use `LinkedList`, I'm wondering how to do this?

Comment: LinkedList<LinkedList<Node>>

Comment: But if I do something like that, I get an error that `LinkedList` does not accept parameters. I'm using the same class to create `Nodes`, and then trying to create a list that holds a stack of these `Nodes`. Do I have to add each `Node` individually? But then it defeats the purpose of `stacks`.

Comment: @RomanC while your answer maybe correct. Please answer the question in the answers section and use the comments section to ask for more clarity or improvisations.

Comment: @UmaKanth No, dear, the comments section is for comments, and I have enough reputation to write comments there and here. And what I'm writing in comments does matter, if you don't understand a comment or answer don't respond, otherwise you'll be a subject for offense.

Comment: @RomanC I think the LinkedList above is not the [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) from Java. Therefore I don't think  this `LinkedList<LinkedList<Node>>`  would work .. please correct me if i'm wrong thx

Comment: @Kami The code above might not compile using java compiler, I don't know why they post a code that doesn't compile. You might try this construction in your answer if you find and resolve errors in code.

Comment: @RomanC you are right. At Kris please provide a  code which we can run and  maybe you should try one of the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementations of Java itself. Before constructing your own class.

Comment: @Kami *how do I make it a new `LinkedList` to accept `LinkedList`s of these `Node`s*, the first what comes to mind is in my first comment. I see that OP thinking about stacks but I didn't see any stack in the code.

Comment: @RomanC  when I read the this question at first, the same solution of yours came into my mind also. Then I realized that this is not the same `LinkedList` I knew from Java. Kris if you want to create a `Stack` you can read this [article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaDatastructures/article.html#stack)

Comment: @RomanC, My apologies for any confusion. My pop() and push() methods are in my `LinkedList` class, so while they're not named `Stack stack`, my `LinkedList stack` behaves exactly like one. I'm just misunderstanding how I can have my `LinkedList` class to have both parameters that accept just Nodes, and to accept LinkedList<Node> like you suggested.

Comment: @Kris you can try to create an Superclass from which the `LinkedList` and Node are `extends` but I think this would be a messy solution, because it seems  `LinkedList` and a `Node` have nothing in common within your project. Therefor it would be better if you just use an existing `LinkedList` implementation.

Comment: @Kami I've edited the question to make it properly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I just gave it a shot - using the Java Collection Framework as mentioned by *Kami* and *Roman C*. To avoid confusion I always used the full qualified name of the interfaces/classes involved - *even though that makes the code look big and ugly*.

I used the `java.util.LinkedList` which implements the `java.util.List` as well as the `java.util.Deque` interface. The latter one gives you the methods to treat it as a stack.

I assume from the method name, that you actually want to sort the Nodes in your stack. For that I had to change some parts of your original example, since it seemed not to behave like you described.

I ended up with the following variation of your example:

```
public void sort(java.util.Deque<Node> stackOfIntNodes) {
    java.util.List<java.util.Deque<Node>> piles =
            new java.util.LinkedList<java.util.Deque<Node>>();
    java.util.Deque<Node> currentStack = new java.util.LinkedList<Node>();
    inputLoop : while (!stackOfIntNodes.isEmpty()) {
        Node currentNode = stackOfIntNodes.pop();
        for (java.util.Deque<Node> singlePile : piles) {
            // check first element of each pile
            Node smallestNodeInSinglePile = singlePile.peek();
            Object valueOfSmallestNodeInSinglePile =
                    smallestNodeInSinglePile.getData();
            if ((((java.lang.Comparable) valueOfSmallestNodeInSinglePile)
                    .compareTo(currentNode.getData())) <= 0) {
                singlePile.push(currentNode);
                continue inputLoop;
            }
        }
        piles.add(currentStack);
        currentStack = new java.util.LinkedList<Node>();
        currentStack.push(currentNode); // put value in stack
    }
    piles.add(currentStack);
    java.util.Deque<Node> sortedStackOfIntNodes = new java.util.LinkedList<Node>();
    for (java.util.Deque<Node> singlePile : piles) {
        while (!singlePile.isEmpty()) {
            sortedStackOfIntNodes.push(singlePile.pop());
        }
    }
    // RESULT: you got all your Node elements in sorted order
}
```

But if you were really using the `java.util.LinkedList` instead of your own implementation, you could easily use this equivalent method:

```
public void sort(java.util.Deque<Node> stackOfIntNodes) {
    java.util.LinkedList<Node> sortedListOfIntNodes =
            new java.util.LinkedList<Node>(stackOfIntNodes);
    java.util.Collections.sort(sortedListOfIntNodes,
            new Comparator<Node>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Node nodeOne, Node nodeTwo) {
                    return ((java.lang.Comparable) nodeOne.getData())
                            .compareTo(nodeTwo.getData());
        }
    });
    // RESULT: you got all your Node elements in sorted order
}
```

Depending on your actual Node class and/or own LinkedList, you might have to apply further changes here.

Comment: Just for interest sakes, why do you always use the full qualified names? It obviously increases confusion due to the bulkiness, so I'm guess you mix implementations regularly or is there some performance gain?

Comment: @Ian2thedv just because there was a lengthy discussion about the OP using a custom LinkedList class, that was not the Java.util.LinkedList (see the first paragraph of my answer). Normally I avoid full qualifiers at all costs ;-)